# Find font size that gives me

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm writing some code that will render some text at an image. I want the text to take the image width.

I know the image width
I want to know fontwidth(text, ?) = image width
I can take an arbitrary value to as fontwidth(text, 32) = y to start.

Today I'm using a binary search to find out the closer value as I can get.

Is there a clever way to reach this?
I need to know if fontwidth(text, x) is linear, if it is is possible to find out right?

I though about rule of 3 but since I have a f(x) and not simply x I can't get through it.

-- Edit --

Sorry I couldn't explain better, to simplify for $f(x) = K$, I want to find $x$, and $K$ is known

$f(x)$ is *"pretty linenar"*

[image: https://imgur.com/a/7kyTtUd]

Comment: Your question is not very clear and seems that it is supposed to be posted in tex stack exchange.

Comment: As I see it, you're essentially asking this question: "I have a function $f(x)$ and I need it to have a value $y$, so $f(x) =y$. How can I find the value of $x$ that will give this value?". For a problem like this, it would indeed be a good idea to know as much as possible about the function $f(x)$. If it's linear, great, the problem will be simple. But if you know absolutely nothing about the function, then you have to resort to trial-and-error.

Comment: By the way, what is "rule of 3" in this context?

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for your reply. The function is not exactly linear but I can work with the approximation I will update the question

Comment: Rule of three does not apply here, I guess, it was, if I have a relation $a \rightarrow b$, $c \rightarrow $x, then I can $x = ab/c$, but in this case I have $x$, and want to know $f(x)$

Comment: If you can assume the function is linear, then choose two values of $x$, say $10$ and $50$, and compute $f(x)$. This gives you the equation of the line. Substitute your value of $y$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: Thanks @rogerl for your answer. I'm looking for definition of $f(x)$, which I can achieve by applying two values to it, then the the inverse of $f(x)$  so that $f^{-1}(K)$ gives me $x$ right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, take $f(10) = 110$ and $f(50) = 310$ (which look like decent approximations to your curve). The equation of the line is then
$$y-310 = \frac{310-110}{50-10}(x-50),$$
or
$$y = 5x+60.$$
If you want to find $f(x)=200$, then solve $200 = 5x+60$ giving $x = 28$.

Comment: Thanks rogerl I will implement this, thank you so much to pointing me the direction